# C# deploy dependency files?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, clickonce

I need to deploy a project that uses an API. That API has a series of dependent DLLs (about a dozen). I use ClickOnce to deploy my apps. I'm trying to figure out the best way to build my project, include the dependencies and still use ClickOnce.

1. I think post-build script(s) might make the most sense for this. Is there another way to do this?
2. Some of my users will need the new API functionality, others will not. Is there a way to include the dependency files in one build and not another? For example, I want "Debug" to include the API dependencies while "Release" should not.

Answer (score 2):

You can add all the dependencies as references to the project, they will then get deployed with it.

You will not be able to have separate files with this method, however.

Comment: There's about a dozen or so of these files and I'd rather deploy them as a bulk copy or something like that.

Comment: @Jim - And how does my suggestion stop you from doing that?

Comment: This should not be down-voted.  This is how it should be done.  Correct answer, @Oded.  Why would you want to "bulk copy or something"?  ClickOnce is essentially the same thing and you'll get automatic updates whenever your dependencies change.  Don't make it more work than it needs to be.